# Bootstrap-table converts html tags to text (or escape sequence) in cell

Tags: bootstrap-table

I've just upgraded to Bootstrap-table 1.10.0. (from 1.9.0)  It now seems that any html tags added to a cell (eg. "<div></div>") is converted to text (or  escape sequence).  There seems to be a "data-formatter" that can be used as a workaround but its usage is limiting for my purpose.

Is there a setting to add to a bootstrap-table or cell to accept html tags as is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing it as well, created an issue on the github tracker: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/1933

From github: add data-escape to the table tag